Help me transition from academia (ongoing PhD) to industry
I'm a first-year PhD student in the US with a student visa (F-1). I'm contemplating moving from academia to industry and eventually obtaining an MBA. Please help me strategize the transition. For clarification, I will drop out immediately after the job and the work-related visa are secured.

The H1B Visa is a tough nut to crack. Is there a way I can obtain a work visa (H1B included) before I drop out of my PhD? My only source of income right now is the stipend, and in case I don't get the visa, I'll have an option to fall back and re-apply later. I'm concerned because the H1B requires me to have a job at hand (before application) and the job provider is unlikely going to allow me to continue with the PhD (instead of joining his/her office) till the visa gets approved.
I'm about to start applying for jobs. Will the "PhD : 2023-" in the resume deter potential employers from offering me a (job) interview? I think many companies auto-reject current students applying for full-time roles.



Is there a way I can obtain a work visa (H1B included) before I drop out of my PhD?

Yes. You can file for H1B whole on an F1. One of the more difficult hurdles to clear is the lottery which is (by nature) unpredictable. So, in a way, being on your PHD program is helpful. You have a steady income and a fallback position if the lottery fails.

Will the "PhD : 2023-" in the resume deter potential employers from offering me a (job) interview?

Yes. Many employers are looking for employees that can start soon-ish. You won't be able to land any of these jobs. But "many" is not all. You just have to keep applying (AND networking) to find one who is the patience and enough interest in your skills to go the extra mile with you.

I appreciate your efforts. Unfortunately, the site won't allow me to upvote your answer. Anyways, does the list of companies that may be willing to go the extra mile with me include large companies, especially the Fortune 100 tech companies/banks? Or is it always the smaller ones? Just trying to figure out which way it is skewed or if there's any!

I don't think there is a skew one way or another. Your best bet is to network in your academic field wherever it intersects what some interesting companies do. Present yourself, meet people, talk to them and see if anything clicks. That's how I got my H1B (with a PhD and working in academia) and even relocation into a different country. However, that's a while ago.

You write that you are a first-year PhD student. So for a 3-yer program you would expect to get your PhD in the summer of 2026. You can definitely apply for jobs in spring 2026 expecting to start work in late summer/ early fall 2026 with PhD in hand.
Applying now in early 2024 for a job start in 2026 will get you automatically rejected. No one knows whether in 2 years you will actually have managed to get a PhD (PhD are hard, a lot of people drop out or take longer than planned). And the vast majority of companies does not plan their positions 2 years into the future.

I meant, I will drop out right after I get the job. Won't attempt to finish the PhD at all. (Edit: Post edited. Added a clarification.)
